# how to update linux on Amazon

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Below is the MSG I get when I log in to my EC2 instant. How can I  update my instant to the new Linux version?

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|
```

See /usr/share/doc/system-release/ for latest release notes.
Amazon Linux version 2013.03 is available.

Answer (score 0):

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ you can always update your AMI as per your requiremens and customize too.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thanks but how do I update it. The link provided does not talk about steps on how to update.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/79123/re-bundle-or-update-an-ec2-ami this would be helpful